# How can I put <Input> <datalist> it in the JS file because is increasing weight of HTML?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have to pass a huge dataset of list of cities/ locations in a particular country to the users because it is going to be reusable.

I can simply put it in the HTML code like so:

```
<datalist id="cities">
<option value="Mumbai">
<option value="New Delhi">
<option value="Moscow">
<option value="New York">
<option value="Washington">
</datalist>
```

I feel that each time the user reloads the page, the whole thing makes the HTML file very heavy.

Can I somehow put it in the JS file and pass it to the DOM/HTML without any attached bulky code?

a) Can this be done
b) Is this a good idea in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some fiddling and looking around, I found  a solution to the problem myself.

It involves the use of javascript. 
To this piece of HTML code:

I  added this simple javascript.

```
<script>
datalist=document.getElementById("countries");
datalist.empty();
datalist.append("<option value="India"><option value="Vietnam"><option value="Russia"><option value="Greece"><option value="New Zealand">")
</script>
```

And it works.

Now my next aim will be to get this append to be populated by a for next loop. That will make the code even smaller for a large data-list.